# How to build YAML parser using tatsu python parser generator

Tags: tatsu

How to build YAML parser using [tatsu](https://github.com/neogeny/TatSu) python parser generator?
Parsing indent-based language like YAML is difficult, so I cannot achieve this.

Comment: This has been asked many times. You should search for previous answers. This is one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356638/how-would-you-parse-indentation-python-style

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you parse indentation (python style)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356638/how-would-you-parse-indentation-python-style)

Comment: No, I don't want to know generic method, I want to know tatsu specific way.

Comment: How to generate INDENT or DEDENT token using tatsu? it is seems not documented.

Answer (score 0):

TatSu was used to do experiments and bootstrap the new PEG parser in Python.

You can find the solutions to `INDENT`/`DEDENT` I used in the original efforts here:

https://github.com/neogeny/pygl